# Express airflow task dependency to a task that is not a direct parent

Tags: airflow

I have a quite basic airflow workflow and one small obstacle I cannot seem to overcome. So my goal would be to have two groups of tasks. First the first group should run then the next one. The issue is that in group 2, I would need to create dependencies to tasks from group 1. If a certain task in group 1 failed then we can skip it's dependency from group 2.

So, this is a layout I can easily achieve:
[image]

```
dag = DAG(
    'Example',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)


def get_task(name):
    return BashOperator(
        task_id=name,
        bash_command='date',
        dag=dag,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )


t = [get_task(f'Task_{n+1}') for n in range(3)]
d = [get_task(f'Should_depend_on_task_{n+1}') for n in range(3)]

start = get_task('start')
intermediate = get_task('wait_for_1_2_3')
intermediate2 = get_task('wait_for_4_5_6')
end = get_task('end')

start >> t >> intermediate >> d >> intermediate2 >> end
```

But what I actually need would be something like that (pink means skipped):
[image]

So I'm looking for a way to dynamically design such dependencies. Or I think what I would actually need would be to dynamically say that I want to skip a task. Any help much appreciated. I was thinking about using XCOM, but then I have no idea how to skip a task in runtime. An option would be to use the `PythonBranchOperator`, but I would need to append it to each and every task which seems a bit to complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with this mixin that allows you to set a task state to skipped if any of the tasks it depends on has not succeded:

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.utils.state import State


class SkippableOperatorMixin:
    """
    This mixin extends an Airflow operators functionality with
    the ability to skip its execution if any of the tasks it depends on did not succeed.
    """
    depends_on_tasks = []

    def __init__(self, depends_on_tasks=[], **kwargs):
        self.depends_on_tasks = depends_on_tasks
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _get_subdag_id_and_task_id(self, task_id):
        """
        Gets the subdag_id and task_id from the task_id

        Example:
          Task1 => (None, 'Task1')
          MainDag.SubDag1.Task1 => ('MainDag.SubDag1', 'Task1')
        """
        task_arr = task_id.split('.')
        return '.'.join(task_arr[:-1]), task_arr[-1]

    @provide_session
    def current_state(self, task_id, execution_date, session=None):
        """
        Get the very latest state of a task identified by the task_id and execution_date from the database.
        """
        TI = TaskInstance
        dag_id, task_id = self._get_subdag_id_and_task_id(task_id)

        qry = session.query(TI).filter(
            TI.task_id == task_id,
            TI.execution_date == execution_date,
        )

        if dag_id:
            qry = qry.filter(TI.dag_id == dag_id)

        ti = qry.all()

        if ti:
            state = ti[0].state
        else:
            state = None
        return state

    def pre_execute(self, context):
        execution_date = context['execution_date']
        skip_task = False
        prerequisite_states = [self.current_state(task_id, execution_date) for task_id in self.depends_on_tasks]
        for state in prerequisite_states:
            if state != State.SUCCESS:
                skip_task = True

        if skip_task:
            raise AirflowSkipException
```

Example usage:

```
class MySkippableOperator(SkippableOperatorMixin, MyOperator):
    pass


task = MySkippableOperator(
    # All the properties you would pass to YourOperator
    depends_on_tasks = ['TaskId1', 'TaskId2']
)
```